# How to store every viewpager page position in list of them?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview

I have a list of viewpagers with **UnderlinePageIndicator** in RecyclerView, about 30 in one fragment. I want to store the page position of every pager in object mFlat, and to retrive it from mFlat on every pager update with the help of

```
flatViewHolder.pager.setCurrentItem(mFlat.get(RecyclerViewPosition).getCur_pos());
```

So when i try to save the current page of the first pager it is ok. But after scroll the page down every pager seems to get this page number - which is wrong. I want to store every pagers page number. Here is my viewpager addOnPageChangeListener

```
flatViewHolder.pager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int pos, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int pos) {
                // save current page pos in mFlat object
                mFlat.get(position).setCur_pos(pos);
            }
            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
            }
        });
```

and this fires everytime on different viewpagers when i scroll the page

```
@Override
                public void onPageSelected(int pos) {
                    // save current page pos in mFlat object
                    mFlat.get(position).setCur_pos(pos);
                }
```

Comment: This is how the view holder pattern works. The whole point of the pattern is to reuse the references to views in inflated layouts. The `RecyclerView` formalizes this pattern. Example: Create a dummy `RecyclerView` with enough items in the adapter so that it scrolls. Now create a view with a couple `TextView`s in it. On the first position, set all the `TextViews`. Set only one of them for all the other items. Now scroll up and down. You'll see that the text you set in the first position wont get cleared out all the time. Same idea with your problem with the `OnPageChangeListener`.

Comment: @MichaelDeSoto so what i have to do?

Comment: @MichaelDeSoto by the way, in my case every viewpager have different id ( setId() )

Comment: Check out my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is that you're calling `addOnPageChangeListener`:

```
viewHolder.pager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {[...]}
```

Since the reference to pager is maintained, each time you scroll you're adding a new listener. When that listener is triggered, your `position` variable is getting used in all the listeners associated with the pager reference.

So, the quick and dirty solution, I think, is to use `setOnPageChangeListener`. *This method is deprecated*, but it hasn't been removed from the APIs yet. Calling `set` instead of `add` will replace the listener currently associated with the pager with your new one. So only one listener will ever be invoked.

Try it. I *think* it'll get you where you need to go.

Comment: still the same situation. when i change position in viewpager and start scrolling with recycler onPageSelected() fires an different viewpagers

Comment: even try to set setOnPageChangeListener to PageIndicator - the same situation

Answer (score 2):

you need to do the reference in onPageScrolled too,  Add:

```
   @Override
   public void onPageScrolled(int pos, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

         // Update reference for page scroll too
         mFlat.get(position).setCur_pos(pos);
    }
```

when you scroll the page its never updating, only if you select the page will it update, as you have above.